# How to dynamically replace contents of HTML tags with Python on Google App Engine with lxml?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, lxml

I am using Google app engine and python to build an application. I am incredibly new to python as well as GAE. I have a index.html file with the basic template for my site.  However I would like to replace the contents of a few tags depending on the URL. For example update the title tag for each individual pages. From what I can tell the recommended way to do this is using the lxml library.

And so... Tonight is my first time I have ever worked with lxml and I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around it. I have been fooling around with several permutations of the basic syntax and have not had much success understanding how it works. I have looked for different tutorials and the documentation is few and far between.

When I try the following code I get a 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'find_class' error, however the documentation here: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html it sure looks like it should have that class

Am I on the right path?  Is this the most efficient/best way to replace the content of html tags?

```
import os
import webapp2
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.parse('index.html')
doc.find_class("title") == 'About Page'
self.response.write(lxml.html.tostring(doc))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not the way to that on Google App Engine. You should use some kind of template framework like Jinja2 or Django to achieve your goal.

But before all that you will have to make sure that you completed the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/), where you can see these things in action.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,  I have not looked into any of the template frameworks yet and I was hoping to avoid having to learn them as I only have 3 separate pages and only have two or three tags I am interested in replacing.

Comment: @TheAskerOfQuestions that's exactly why you should do the getting started first.. there is nothing that you should afraid of.

Comment: Jinja2 also comes inbuilt to webapp2. It's a good place to start. http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/index.html